# TPS/MAP calculation problem - SOLVED

Tags: arduino-uno, programming

In my recent project, I have to create TPS/MAP table, which is provide value of LOAD.

Here, it is my table. You can see two value of LOAD which is separate by /. (TPS LOAD / MAP LOAD)

[image: TPS/MAP Table]

But now here as you can see, TPS provide different value of LOAD and MAP provide different value of LOAD. So, every cell has a two value of LOAD. So, I decide just add this both LOAD and divide it by 2.

I made program for this but it access only just LAST COLUMN and LAST ROW and it provide wrong value of LOAD. I don't understand why this happen.

Here, my code.

```
float TPS[] = {0, 0.4, 0.8, 1.2, 1.6, 2, 2.4, 2.8, 3.2, 3.6, 4, 4.4, 4.8, 5};
float MAP[] = {0.85, 0.95, 1.05, 1.15, 1.25, 1.35, 1.45, 1.55, 1.65, 1.75, 1.85, 1.9};

float TPS_MIN = 0.00;
float TPS_MAX = 5.00;

float MAP_MIN = 0.85;
float MAP_MAX = 1.90;

float LOAD_MIN_TPS[] = {2, 3.23, 4.49, 5.73, 6.97, 8.22, 9.44, 10.63, 11.87, 13.11, 14.33, 15.00};
float LOAD_MAX_TPS[] = {10.00, 17.08, 24.11, 31.67, 38.30, 45.73, 52.63, 60.19, 67.22, 74.52, 81.68, 85.00};

float LOAD_MIN_MAP[] = {2, 2.64, 3.28, 3.92, 4.56, 5.21, 5.85, 6.47, 7.11, 7.76, 8.40, 9.05, 9.69, 10.00};
float LOAD_MAX_MAP[] = {15.00, 20.62, 26.17, 31.79, 37.35, 42.97, 48.66, 54.14, 59.76, 65.38, 70.93, 76.63, 82.18, 85.00};

float m1[12] = {};
float m2[14] = {};

float y1[14] = {};
float y2[12] = {};

float y[168] = {};

int i, j, n;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{ 
  for(j = 0; j < 12; j++)
  {
    m1[j] = (LOAD_MAX_TPS[j] - LOAD_MIN_TPS[j]) / (TPS_MAX - TPS_MIN);

    Serial.print("m1 : ");
    Serial.println(m1[j]);

    for(i = 0; i < 14; i++)
    {
      y1[i] = m1[j] * (TPS[i] - TPS_MIN) + LOAD_MIN_TPS[j];

      Serial.print("TPS : ");
      Serial.print(TPS[i]);
      Serial.print("\t");
      Serial.print("LOAD : ");
      Serial.println(y1[i]);
   }
  }

  for(i = 0; i < 14; i++)
  {
    m2[i] = (LOAD_MAX_MAP[i] - LOAD_MIN_MAP[i]) / (MAP_MAX - MAP_MIN);

    Serial.print("m2 : ");
    Serial.println(m2[i]);

    for(j = 0; j < 12; j++)
    {
      y2[j] = m2[i] * (MAP[j] - MAP_MIN) + LOAD_MIN_MAP[i];

      Serial.print("MAP : ");
      Serial.print(MAP[j]);
      Serial.print("\t");
      Serial.print("LOAD : ");
      Serial.println(y2[j]);
    }
   }

  for(i = 0; i < 14; i++)
  {
    for(j = 0; j < 12; j++)
    {
      y[n] = (y1[i] + y2[j]) / 2;
      Serial.print("LOAD TPS : ");
      Serial.print(y1[i]);
      Serial.print("\t");
      Serial.print("LOAD MAP : ");
      Serial.print(y2[j]);
      Serial.print("\t");
      Serial.print("TPS : ");
      Serial.print(TPS[i]);
      Serial.print("\t");
      Serial.print("MAP : ");
      Serial.print(MAP[j]);
      Serial.print("\t");
      Serial.print("Final LOAD : ");
      Serial.println(y[n]);
    }
  }
  delay(1000000);
}
```

My serial monitor output :

```
LOAD TPS : 15.00    LOAD MAP : 10.00    TPS : 0.00  MAP : 0.85  Final LOAD : 12.50
LOAD TPS : 15.00    LOAD MAP : 17.14    TPS : 0.00  MAP : 0.95  Final LOAD : 16.07
LOAD TPS : 15.00    LOAD MAP : 24.29    TPS : 0.00  MAP : 1.05  Final LOAD : 19.64
LOAD TPS : 15.00    LOAD MAP : 31.43    TPS : 0.00  MAP : 1.15  Final LOAD : 23.21
LOAD TPS : 15.00    LOAD MAP : 38.57    TPS : 0.00  MAP : 1.25  Final LOAD : 26.79
LOAD TPS : 15.00    LOAD MAP : 45.71    TPS : 0.00  MAP : 1.35  Final LOAD : 30.36
LOAD TPS : 15.00    LOAD MAP : 52.86    TPS : 0.00  MAP : 1.45  Final LOAD : 33.93
LOAD TPS : 15.00    LOAD MAP : 60.00    TPS : 0.00  MAP : 1.55  Final LOAD : 37.50
LOAD TPS : 15.00    LOAD MAP : 67.14    TPS : 0.00  MAP : 1.65  Final LOAD : 41.07
LOAD TPS : 15.00    LOAD MAP : 74.29    TPS : 0.00  MAP : 1.75  Final LOAD : 44.64
LOAD TPS : 15.00    LOAD MAP : 81.43    TPS : 0.00  MAP : 1.85  Final LOAD : 48.21
LOAD TPS : 15.00    LOAD MAP : 85.00    TPS : 0.00  MAP : 1.90  Final LOAD : 50.00
LOAD TPS : 20.60    LOAD MAP : 10.00    TPS : 0.40  MAP : 0.85  Final LOAD : 15.30
LOAD TPS : 20.60    LOAD MAP : 17.14    TPS : 0.40  MAP : 0.95  Final LOAD : 18.87
LOAD TPS : 20.60    LOAD MAP : 24.29    TPS : 0.40  MAP : 1.05  Final LOAD : 22.44
LOAD TPS : 20.60    LOAD MAP : 31.43    TPS : 0.40  MAP : 1.15  Final LOAD : 26.01
LOAD TPS : 20.60    LOAD MAP : 38.57    TPS : 0.40  MAP : 1.25  Final LOAD : 29.59
LOAD TPS : 20.60    LOAD MAP : 45.71    TPS : 0.40  MAP : 1.35  Final LOAD : 33.16
LOAD TPS : 20.60    LOAD MAP : 52.86    TPS : 0.40  MAP : 1.45  Final LOAD : 36.73
LOAD TPS : 20.60    LOAD MAP : 60.00    TPS : 0.40  MAP : 1.55  Final LOAD : 40.30
LOAD TPS : 20.60    LOAD MAP : 67.14    TPS : 0.40  MAP : 1.65  Final LOAD : 43.87
LOAD TPS : 20.60    LOAD MAP : 74.29    TPS : 0.40  MAP : 1.75  Final LOAD : 47.44
LOAD TPS : 20.60    LOAD MAP : 81.43    TPS : 0.40  MAP : 1.85  Final LOAD : 51.01
LOAD TPS : 20.60    LOAD MAP : 85.00    TPS : 0.40  MAP : 1.90  Final LOAD : 52.80
LOAD TPS : 26.20    LOAD MAP : 10.00    TPS : 0.80  MAP : 0.85  Final LOAD : 18.10
LOAD TPS : 26.20    LOAD MAP : 17.14    TPS : 0.80  MAP : 0.95  Final LOAD : 21.67
LOAD TPS : 26.20    LOAD MAP : 24.29    TPS : 0.80  MAP : 1.05  Final LOAD : 25.24
LOAD TPS : 26.20    LOAD MAP : 31.43    TPS : 0.80  MAP : 1.15  Final LOAD : 28.81
LOAD TPS : 26.20    LOAD MAP : 38.57    TPS : 0.80  MAP : 1.25  Final LOAD : 32.39
LOAD TPS : 26.20    LOAD MAP : 45.71    TPS : 0.80  MAP : 1.35  Final LOAD : 35.96
LOAD TPS : 26.20    LOAD MAP : 52.86    TPS : 0.80  MAP : 1.45  Final LOAD : 39.53
LOAD TPS : 26.20    LOAD MAP : 60.00    TPS : 0.80  MAP : 1.55  Final LOAD : 43.10
LOAD TPS : 26.20    LOAD MAP : 67.14    TPS : 0.80  MAP : 1.65  Final LOAD : 46.67
LOAD TPS : 26.20    LOAD MAP : 74.29    TPS : 0.80  MAP : 1.75  Final LOAD : 50.24
LOAD TPS : 26.20    LOAD MAP : 81.43    TPS : 0.80  MAP : 1.85  Final LOAD : 53.81
LOAD TPS : 26.20    LOAD MAP : 85.00    TPS : 0.80  MAP : 1.90  Final LOAD : 55.60
LOAD TPS : 31.80    LOAD MAP : 10.00    TPS : 1.20  MAP : 0.85  Final LOAD : 20.90
LOAD TPS : 31.80    LOAD MAP : 17.14    TPS : 1.20  MAP : 0.95  Final LOAD : 24.47
LOAD TPS : 31.80    LOAD MAP : 24.29    TPS : 1.20  MAP : 1.05  Final LOAD : 28.04
LOAD TPS : 31.80    LOAD MAP : 31.43    TPS : 1.20  MAP : 1.15  Final LOAD : 31.61
LOAD TPS : 31.80    LOAD MAP : 38.57    TPS : 1.20  MAP : 1.25  Final LOAD : 35.19
LOAD TPS : 31.80    LOAD MAP : 45.71    TPS : 1.20  MAP : 1.35  Final LOAD : 38.76
LOAD TPS : 31.80    LOAD MAP : 52.86    TPS : 1.20  MAP : 1.45  Final LOAD : 42.33
LOAD TPS : 31.80    LOAD MAP : 60.00    TPS : 1.20  MAP : 1.55  Final LOAD : 45.90
LOAD TPS : 31.80    LOAD MAP : 67.14    TPS : 1.20  MAP : 1.65  Final LOAD : 49.47
LOAD TPS : 31.80    LOAD MAP : 74.29    TPS : 1.20  MAP : 1.75  Final LOAD : 53.04
LOAD TPS : 31.80    LOAD MAP : 81.43    TPS : 1.20  MAP : 1.85  Final LOAD : 56.61
LOAD TPS : 31.80    LOAD MAP : 85.00    TPS : 1.20  MAP : 1.90  Final LOAD : 58.40
LOAD TPS : 37.40    LOAD MAP : 10.00    TPS : 1.60  MAP : 0.85  Final LOAD : 23.70
LOAD TPS : 37.40    LOAD MAP : 17.14    TPS : 1.60  MAP : 0.95  Final LOAD : 27.27
LOAD TPS : 37.40    LOAD MAP : 24.29    TPS : 1.60  MAP : 1.05  Final LOAD : 30.84
LOAD TPS : 37.40    LOAD MAP : 31.43    TPS : 1.60  MAP : 1.15  Final LOAD : 34.41
LOAD TPS : 37.40    LOAD MAP : 38.57    TPS : 1.60  MAP : 1.25  Final LOAD : 37.99
LOAD TPS : 37.40    LOAD MAP : 45.71    TPS : 1.60  MAP : 1.35  Final LOAD : 41.56
LOAD TPS : 37.40    LOAD MAP : 52.86    TPS : 1.60  MAP : 1.45  Final LOAD : 45.13
LOAD TPS : 37.40    LOAD MAP : 60.00    TPS : 1.60  MAP : 1.55  Final LOAD : 48.70
LOAD TPS : 37.40    LOAD MAP : 67.14    TPS : 1.60  MAP : 1.65  Final LOAD : 52.27
LOAD TPS : 37.40    LOAD MAP : 74.29    TPS : 1.60  MAP : 1.75  Final LOAD : 55.84
LOAD TPS : 37.40    LOAD MAP : 81.43    TPS : 1.60  MAP : 1.85  Final LOAD : 59.41
LOAD TPS : 37.40    LOAD MAP : 85.00    TPS : 1.60  MAP : 1.90  Final LOAD : 61.20
LOAD TPS : 43.00    LOAD MAP : 10.00    TPS : 2.00  MAP : 0.85  Final LOAD : 26.50
LOAD TPS : 43.00    LOAD MAP : 17.14    TPS : 2.00  MAP : 0.95  Final LOAD : 30.07
LOAD TPS : 43.00    LOAD MAP : 24.29    TPS : 2.00  MAP : 1.05  Final LOAD : 33.64
LOAD TPS : 43.00    LOAD MAP : 31.43    TPS : 2.00  MAP : 1.15  Final LOAD : 37.21
LOAD TPS : 43.00    LOAD MAP : 38.57    TPS : 2.00  MAP : 1.25  Final LOAD : 40.79
LOAD TPS : 43.00    LOAD MAP : 45.71    TPS : 2.00  MAP : 1.35  Final LOAD : 44.36
LOAD TPS : 43.00    LOAD MAP : 52.86    TPS : 2.00  MAP : 1.45  Final LOAD : 47.93
LOAD TPS : 43.00    LOAD MAP : 60.00    TPS : 2.00  MAP : 1.55  Final LOAD : 51.50
LOAD TPS : 43.00    LOAD MAP : 67.14    TPS : 2.00  MAP : 1.65  Final LOAD : 55.07
LOAD TPS : 43.00    LOAD MAP : 74.29    TPS : 2.00  MAP : 1.75  Final LOAD : 58.64
LOAD TPS : 43.00    LOAD MAP : 81.43    TPS : 2.00  MAP : 1.85  Final LOAD : 62.21
LOAD TPS : 43.00    LOAD MAP : 85.00    TPS : 2.00  MAP : 1.90  Final LOAD : 64.00
LOAD TPS : 48.60    LOAD MAP : 10.00    TPS : 2.40  MAP : 0.85  Final LOAD : 29.30
LOAD TPS : 48.60    LOAD MAP : 17.14    TPS : 2.40  MAP : 0.95  Final LOAD : 32.87
LOAD TPS : 48.60    LOAD MAP : 24.29    TPS : 2.40  MAP : 1.05  Final LOAD : 36.44
LOAD TPS : 48.60    LOAD MAP : 31.43    TPS : 2.40  MAP : 1.15  Final LOAD : 40.01
LOAD TPS : 48.60    LOAD MAP : 38.57    TPS : 2.40  MAP : 1.25  Final LOAD : 43.59
LOAD TPS : 48.60    LOAD MAP : 45.71    TPS : 2.40  MAP : 1.35  Final LOAD : 47.16
LOAD TPS : 48.60    LOAD MAP : 52.86    TPS : 2.40  MAP : 1.45  Final LOAD : 50.73
LOAD TPS : 48.60    LOAD MAP : 60.00    TPS : 2.40  MAP : 1.55  Final LOAD : 54.30
LOAD TPS : 48.60    LOAD MAP : 67.14    TPS : 2.40  MAP : 1.65  Final LOAD : 57.87
LOAD TPS : 48.60    LOAD MAP : 74.29    TPS : 2.40  MAP : 1.75  Final LOAD : 61.44
LOAD TPS : 48.60    LOAD MAP : 81.43    TPS : 2.40  MAP : 1.85  Final LOAD : 65.01
LOAD TPS : 48.60    LOAD MAP : 85.00    TPS : 2.40  MAP : 1.90  Final LOAD : 66.80
LOAD TPS : 54.20    LOAD MAP : 10.00    TPS : 2.80  MAP : 0.85  Final LOAD : 32.10
LOAD TPS : 54.20    LOAD MAP : 17.14    TPS : 2.80  MAP : 0.95  Final LOAD : 35.67
LOAD TPS : 54.20    LOAD MAP : 24.29    TPS : 2.80  MAP : 1.05  Final LOAD : 39.24
LOAD TPS : 54.20    LOAD MAP : 31.43    TPS : 2.80  MAP : 1.15  Final LOAD : 42.81
LOAD TPS : 54.20    LOAD MAP : 38.57    TPS : 2.80  MAP : 1.25  Final LOAD : 46.39
LOAD TPS : 54.20    LOAD MAP : 45.71    TPS : 2.80  MAP : 1.35  Final LOAD : 49.96
LOAD TPS : 54.20    LOAD MAP : 52.86    TPS : 2.80  MAP : 1.45  Final LOAD : 53.53
LOAD TPS : 54.20    LOAD MAP : 60.00    TPS : 2.80  MAP : 1.55  Final LOAD : 57.10
LOAD TPS : 54.20    LOAD MAP : 67.14    TPS : 2.80  MAP : 1.65  Final LOAD : 60.67
LOAD TPS : 54.20    LOAD MAP : 74.29    TPS : 2.80  MAP : 1.75  Final LOAD : 64.24
LOAD TPS : 54.20    LOAD MAP : 81.43    TPS : 2.80  MAP : 1.85  Final LOAD : 67.81
LOAD TPS : 54.20    LOAD MAP : 85.00    TPS : 2.80  MAP : 1.90  Final LOAD : 69.60
LOAD TPS : 59.80    LOAD MAP : 10.00    TPS : 3.20  MAP : 0.85  Final LOAD : 34.90
LOAD TPS : 59.80    LOAD MAP : 17.14    TPS : 3.20  MAP : 0.95  Final LOAD : 38.47
LOAD TPS : 59.80    LOAD MAP : 24.29    TPS : 3.20  MAP : 1.05  Final LOAD : 42.04
LOAD TPS : 59.80    LOAD MAP : 31.43    TPS : 3.20  MAP : 1.15  Final LOAD : 45.61
LOAD TPS : 59.80    LOAD MAP : 38.57    TPS : 3.20  MAP : 1.25  Final LOAD : 49.19
LOAD TPS : 59.80    LOAD MAP : 45.71    TPS : 3.20  MAP : 1.35  Final LOAD : 52.76
LOAD TPS : 59.80    LOAD MAP : 52.86    TPS : 3.20  MAP : 1.45  Final LOAD : 56.33
LOAD TPS : 59.80    LOAD MAP : 60.00    TPS : 3.20  MAP : 1.55  Final LOAD : 59.90
LOAD TPS : 59.80    LOAD MAP : 67.14    TPS : 3.20  MAP : 1.65  Final LOAD : 63.47
LOAD TPS : 59.80    LOAD MAP : 74.29    TPS : 3.20  MAP : 1.75  Final LOAD : 67.04
LOAD TPS : 59.80    LOAD MAP : 81.43    TPS : 3.20  MAP : 1.85  Final LOAD : 70.61
LOAD TPS : 59.80    LOAD MAP : 85.00    TPS : 3.20  MAP : 1.90  Final LOAD : 72.40
LOAD TPS : 65.40    LOAD MAP : 10.00    TPS : 3.60  MAP : 0.85  Final LOAD : 37.70
LOAD TPS : 65.40    LOAD MAP : 17.14    TPS : 3.60  MAP : 0.95  Final LOAD : 41.27
LOAD TPS : 65.40    LOAD MAP : 24.29    TPS : 3.60  MAP : 1.05  Final LOAD : 44.84
LOAD TPS : 65.40    LOAD MAP : 31.43    TPS : 3.60  MAP : 1.15  Final LOAD : 48.41
LOAD TPS : 65.40    LOAD MAP : 38.57    TPS : 3.60  MAP : 1.25  Final LOAD : 51.99
LOAD TPS : 65.40    LOAD MAP : 45.71    TPS : 3.60  MAP : 1.35  Final LOAD : 55.56
LOAD TPS : 65.40    LOAD MAP : 52.86    TPS : 3.60  MAP : 1.45  Final LOAD : 59.13
LOAD TPS : 65.40    LOAD MAP : 60.00    TPS : 3.60  MAP : 1.55  Final LOAD : 62.70
LOAD TPS : 65.40    LOAD MAP : 67.14    TPS : 3.60  MAP : 1.65  Final LOAD : 66.27
LOAD TPS : 65.40    LOAD MAP : 74.29    TPS : 3.60  MAP : 1.75  Final LOAD : 69.84
LOAD TPS : 65.40    LOAD MAP : 81.43    TPS : 3.60  MAP : 1.85  Final LOAD : 73.41
LOAD TPS : 65.40    LOAD MAP : 85.00    TPS : 3.60  MAP : 1.90  Final LOAD : 75.20
LOAD TPS : 71.00    LOAD MAP : 10.00    TPS : 4.00  MAP : 0.85  Final LOAD : 40.50
LOAD TPS : 71.00    LOAD MAP : 17.14    TPS : 4.00  MAP : 0.95  Final LOAD : 44.07
LOAD TPS : 71.00    LOAD MAP : 24.29    TPS : 4.00  MAP : 1.05  Final LOAD : 47.64
LOAD TPS : 71.00    LOAD MAP : 31.43    TPS : 4.00  MAP : 1.15  Final LOAD : 51.21
LOAD TPS : 71.00    LOAD MAP : 38.57    TPS : 4.00  MAP : 1.25  Final LOAD : 54.79
LOAD TPS : 71.00    LOAD MAP : 45.71    TPS : 4.00  MAP : 1.35  Final LOAD : 58.36
LOAD TPS : 71.00    LOAD MAP : 52.86    TPS : 4.00  MAP : 1.45  Final LOAD : 61.93
LOAD TPS : 71.00    LOAD MAP : 60.00    TPS : 4.00  MAP : 1.55  Final LOAD : 65.50
LOAD TPS : 71.00    LOAD MAP : 67.14    TPS : 4.00  MAP : 1.65  Final LOAD : 69.07
LOAD TPS : 71.00    LOAD MAP : 74.29    TPS : 4.00  MAP : 1.75  Final LOAD : 72.64
LOAD TPS : 71.00    LOAD MAP : 81.43    TPS : 4.00  MAP : 1.85  Final LOAD : 76.21
LOAD TPS : 71.00    LOAD MAP : 85.00    TPS : 4.00  MAP : 1.90  Final LOAD : 78.00
LOAD TPS : 76.60    LOAD MAP : 10.00    TPS : 4.40  MAP : 0.85  Final LOAD : 43.30
LOAD TPS : 76.60    LOAD MAP : 17.14    TPS : 4.40  MAP : 0.95  Final LOAD : 46.87
LOAD TPS : 76.60    LOAD MAP : 24.29    TPS : 4.40  MAP : 1.05  Final LOAD : 50.44
LOAD TPS : 76.60    LOAD MAP : 31.43    TPS : 4.40  MAP : 1.15  Final LOAD : 54.01
LOAD TPS : 76.60    LOAD MAP : 38.57    TPS : 4.40  MAP : 1.25  Final LOAD : 57.59
LOAD TPS : 76.60    LOAD MAP : 45.71    TPS : 4.40  MAP : 1.35  Final LOAD : 61.16
LOAD TPS : 76.60    LOAD MAP : 52.86    TPS : 4.40  MAP : 1.45  Final LOAD : 64.73
LOAD TPS : 76.60    LOAD MAP : 60.00    TPS : 4.40  MAP : 1.55  Final LOAD : 68.30
LOAD TPS : 76.60    LOAD MAP : 67.14    TPS : 4.40  MAP : 1.65  Final LOAD : 71.87
LOAD TPS : 76.60    LOAD MAP : 74.29    TPS : 4.40  MAP : 1.75  Final LOAD : 75.44
LOAD TPS : 76.60    LOAD MAP : 81.43    TPS : 4.40  MAP : 1.85  Final LOAD : 79.01
LOAD TPS : 76.60    LOAD MAP : 85.00    TPS : 4.40  MAP : 1.90  Final LOAD : 80.80
LOAD TPS : 82.20    LOAD MAP : 10.00    TPS : 4.80  MAP : 0.85  Final LOAD : 46.10
LOAD TPS : 82.20    LOAD MAP : 17.14    TPS : 4.80  MAP : 0.95  Final LOAD : 49.67
LOAD TPS : 82.20    LOAD MAP : 24.29    TPS : 4.80  MAP : 1.05  Final LOAD : 53.24
LOAD TPS : 82.20    LOAD MAP : 31.43    TPS : 4.80  MAP : 1.15  Final LOAD : 56.81
LOAD TPS : 82.20    LOAD MAP : 38.57    TPS : 4.80  MAP : 1.25  Final LOAD : 60.39
LOAD TPS : 82.20    LOAD MAP : 45.71    TPS : 4.80  MAP : 1.35  Final LOAD : 63.96
LOAD TPS : 82.20    LOAD MAP : 52.86    TPS : 4.80  MAP : 1.45  Final LOAD : 67.53
LOAD TPS : 82.20    LOAD MAP : 60.00    TPS : 4.80  MAP : 1.55  Final LOAD : 71.10
LOAD TPS : 82.20    LOAD MAP : 67.14    TPS : 4.80  MAP : 1.65  Final LOAD : 74.67
LOAD TPS : 82.20    LOAD MAP : 74.29    TPS : 4.80  MAP : 1.75  Final LOAD : 78.24
LOAD TPS : 82.20    LOAD MAP : 81.43    TPS : 4.80  MAP : 1.85  Final LOAD : 81.81
LOAD TPS : 82.20    LOAD MAP : 85.00    TPS : 4.80  MAP : 1.90  Final LOAD : 83.60
LOAD TPS : 85.00    LOAD MAP : 10.00    TPS : 5.00  MAP : 0.85  Final LOAD : 47.50
LOAD TPS : 85.00    LOAD MAP : 17.14    TPS : 5.00  MAP : 0.95  Final LOAD : 51.07
LOAD TPS : 85.00    LOAD MAP : 24.29    TPS : 5.00  MAP : 1.05  Final LOAD : 54.64
LOAD TPS : 85.00    LOAD MAP : 31.43    TPS : 5.00  MAP : 1.15  Final LOAD : 58.21
LOAD TPS : 85.00    LOAD MAP : 38.57    TPS : 5.00  MAP : 1.25  Final LOAD : 61.79
LOAD TPS : 85.00    LOAD MAP : 45.71    TPS : 5.00  MAP : 1.35  Final LOAD : 65.36
LOAD TPS : 85.00    LOAD MAP : 52.86    TPS : 5.00  MAP : 1.45  Final LOAD : 68.93
LOAD TPS : 85.00    LOAD MAP : 60.00    TPS : 5.00  MAP : 1.55  Final LOAD : 72.50
LOAD TPS : 85.00    LOAD MAP : 67.14    TPS : 5.00  MAP : 1.65  Final LOAD : 76.07
LOAD TPS : 85.00    LOAD MAP : 74.29    TPS : 5.00  MAP : 1.75  Final LOAD : 79.64
LOAD TPS : 85.00    LOAD MAP : 81.43    TPS : 5.00  MAP : 1.85  Final LOAD : 83.21
LOAD TPS : 85.00    LOAD MAP : 85.00    TPS : 5.00  MAP : 1.90  Final LOAD : 85.00
```

NOTE : Here, I'm not providing all serial monitor output. Just needed part of OUTPUT here displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, this is modified code which provide result which I want.

```
float TPS_MIN = 0.00;
float TPS_MAX = 5.00;

float MAP_MIN = 0.85;
float MAP_MAX = 1.90;

int LOAD_MIN = 2;
int LOAD_MAX = 100;

int RPM_MIN = 400;
int RPM_MAX = 6000;

float LOAD_MIN_TPS_MIN = 2.00;
float LOAD_MAX_TPS_MIN = 10.00;

float LOAD_MIN_TPS_MAX = 15.00;
float LOAD_MAX_TPS_MAX = 85.00;

float LOAD_MIN_MAP_MIN = 2.00;
float LOAD_MAX_MAP_MIN = 15.00;

float LOAD_MIN_MAP_MAX = 10.00;
float LOAD_MAX_MAP_MAX = 85.00;

float injTime_MIN_LOAD_MIN = 4.00;
float injTime_MAX_LOAD_MIN = 4.60;

float injTime_MIN_LOAD_MAX = 8.06;
float injTime_MAX_LOAD_MAX = 14.86;

float injTime_MIN_RPM_MIN = 4.00;
float injTime_MAX_RPM_MIN = 8.06;

float injTime_MIN_RPM_MAX = 4.60;
float injTime_MAX_RPM_MAX = 14.86;


float mTPSmin;
float mTPSmax;
float mMAPmin;
float mMAPmax;

float yTPSmin;
float yTPSmax;
float yMAPmin;
float yMAPmax;

float mTPS;
float mMAP;

float yTPS;
float yMAP;

float LOAD;

float TPS, MAP;

float mLOADmin;
float mLOADmax;
float mRPMmin;
float mRPMmax;

float yLOADmin;
float yLOADmax;
float yRPMmin;
float yRPMmax;

float mLOAD;
float mRPM;

float yLOAD;
float yRPM;

float yInjTime;

int RPM;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{   
    TPS = analogRead(A0) * (5.0 / 1023.0);
    MAP = analogRead(A1) * (1.90 / 1023.0);
    RPM = analogRead(A2) * (6000 / 1023.0);

    mTPSmin = (LOAD_MAX_TPS_MIN - LOAD_MIN_TPS_MIN) / (TPS_MAX - TPS_MIN);

    Serial.print("mTPSmin : ");
    Serial.println(mTPSmin);

    yTPSmin = mTPSmin * (TPS - TPS_MIN) + LOAD_MIN_TPS_MIN;

    Serial.print("TPS : ");
    Serial.print(TPS);
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.print("LOAD : ");
    Serial.println(yTPSmin);

    mTPSmax = (LOAD_MAX_TPS_MAX - LOAD_MIN_TPS_MAX) / (TPS_MAX - TPS_MIN);

    Serial.print("mTPSmax : ");
    Serial.println(mTPSmax);

    yTPSmax = mTPSmax * (TPS - TPS_MIN) + LOAD_MIN_TPS_MAX;

    Serial.print("TPS : ");
    Serial.print(TPS);
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.print("LOAD : ");
    Serial.println(yTPSmax);

    mMAPmin = (LOAD_MAX_MAP_MIN - LOAD_MIN_MAP_MIN) / (MAP_MAX - MAP_MIN);

    Serial.print("mMAPmin : ");
    Serial.println(mMAPmin);

    yMAPmin = mMAPmin * (MAP - MAP_MIN) + LOAD_MIN_MAP_MIN;

    Serial.print("MAP : ");
    Serial.print(MAP);
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.print("LOAD : ");
    Serial.println(yMAPmin);

    mMAPmax = (LOAD_MAX_MAP_MAX - LOAD_MIN_MAP_MAX) / (MAP_MAX - MAP_MIN);

    Serial.print("mMAPmax : ");
    Serial.println(mMAPmax);

    yMAPmax = mMAPmax * (MAP - MAP_MIN) + LOAD_MIN_MAP_MAX;

    Serial.print("MAP : ");
    Serial.print(MAP);
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.print("LOAD : ");
    Serial.println(yMAPmax);

    mTPS = (yMAPmax - yMAPmin) / (TPS_MAX - TPS_MIN);

    Serial.print("mTPS : ");
    Serial.println(mTPS);

    yTPS = mTPS * (TPS - TPS_MIN) + yMAPmin;

    Serial.print("TPS : ");
    Serial.print(TPS);
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.print("LOAD : ");
    Serial.println(yTPS);

    mMAP = (yTPSmax - yTPSmin) / (MAP_MAX - MAP_MIN);

    Serial.print("mMAP : ");
    Serial.println(mMAP);

    yMAP = mMAP * (MAP - MAP_MIN) + yTPSmin;

    Serial.print("MAP : ");
    Serial.print(MAP);
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.print("LOAD : ");
    Serial.println(yMAP);

    LOAD = (yTPS + yMAP) / 2;
    Serial.print("Final LOAD : ");
    Serial.println(LOAD);

    mLOADmin = (injTime_MAX_LOAD_MIN - injTime_MIN_LOAD_MIN) / (LOAD_MAX - LOAD_MIN);

    Serial.print("mLOADmin : ");
    Serial.println(mLOADmin);

    yLOADmin = mLOADmin * (LOAD - LOAD_MIN) + injTime_MIN_LOAD_MIN;

    Serial.print("LOAD : ");
    Serial.print(LOAD);
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.print("injTime : ");
    Serial.println(yLOADmin);

    mLOADmax = (injTime_MAX_LOAD_MAX - injTime_MIN_LOAD_MAX) / (LOAD_MAX - LOAD_MIN);

    Serial.print("mLOADmax : ");
    Serial.println(mLOADmax);

    yLOADmax = mLOADmax * (LOAD - LOAD_MIN) + injTime_MIN_LOAD_MAX;

    Serial.print("LOAD : ");
    Serial.print(LOAD);
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.print("injTime : ");
    Serial.println(yLOADmax);

    mRPMmin = (injTime_MAX_RPM_MIN - injTime_MIN_RPM_MIN) / (RPM_MAX - RPM_MIN);

    Serial.print("mRPMmin : ");
    Serial.println(mRPMmin);

    yRPMmin = mRPMmin * (RPM - RPM_MIN) + injTime_MIN_RPM_MIN;

    Serial.print("RPM : ");
    Serial.print(RPM);
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.print("injTime : ");
    Serial.println(yRPMmin);

    mRPMmax = (injTime_MAX_RPM_MAX - injTime_MIN_RPM_MAX) / (RPM_MAX - RPM_MIN);

    Serial.print("mRPMmax : ");
    Serial.println(mRPMmax);

    yRPMmax = mRPMmax * (RPM - RPM_MIN) + injTime_MIN_RPM_MAX;

    Serial.print("RPM : ");
    Serial.print(RPM);
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.print("injTime : ");
    Serial.println(yRPMmax);

    mLOAD = (yRPMmax - yRPMmin) / (LOAD_MAX - LOAD_MIN);

    Serial.print("mLOAD : ");
    Serial.println(mLOAD);

    yLOAD = mLOAD * (LOAD - LOAD_MIN) + yRPMmin;

    Serial.print("LOAD : ");
    Serial.print(LOAD);
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.print("injTime : ");
    Serial.println(yLOAD);

    mRPM = (yLOADmax - yLOADmin) / (RPM_MAX - RPM_MIN);

    Serial.print("mRPM : ");
    Serial.println(mRPM);

    yRPM = mRPM * (RPM - RPM_MIN) + yLOADmin;

    Serial.print("RPM : ");
    Serial.print(RPM);
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.print("injTime : ");
    Serial.println(yRPM);

    yInjTime = (yLOAD + yRPM) / 2;
    Serial.print("Final injTime : ");
    Serial.println(yInjTime);

    delay(1000000);
}
```